# Finding the count of <td> Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have the following HTML structure and I wanted to find out the length of immediate `<td>s`. here is the code that I am using:-

```
<table class="PrintTable">
    <tr>
      **<td>**
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Type Of Transaction</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      **<td>**
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>2006</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Andi</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>25</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

The function that I am using to find out the length of td is

```
function getBody(element)
{
    var divider=2;
    var originalTable=element.clone();
    var tds = $(originalTable).children('tr').children('td').length;
    alert(tds);


}
```

The result I am seeing is 0. No clue at all. I am expecting 2. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `.clone()`? And is `element` meant to be a jQuery object? I assume so, since `clone` is not a native JS method on a DOM object. Can you please provide an example of how you're invoking `getBody`?

Comment: Yes, element is a JQuery Object and it contains the complete table as object. Even if you do not invoke clone(), still it shows 0 where as I am expecting 2.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I removed the asterisks out of your HTML and made some assumptions about how you're invoking `getBody`, so if I did anything that wasn't right, let me know.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/27ygP/

```
function getBody(element) {
    var divider = 2;
    var originalTable = element.clone();
    var tds = $(originalTable).children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').length;
    alert(tds);
}

getBody($('table.PrintTable'));
```

The big change was the add a `.children('tbody')`. The HTML interpreter wraps the `tr`s in `tbody`. Traverse down into that, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Is there a good debugger where we can find out all these tricks.

Comment: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox is the best tool on the market to navigate the DOM. All of the major browsers have built-in tools to do the same (just click around the menus). It will take you to, among other things, an interactive tree that you can traverse manually.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why you cant use multiple selectors with .children()

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use the following.

```
$("td").length
```

UPDATE

You will want to use the tr tag as the start selector and then count each td selector using first to take just the first one.

```
$("tr", $("td:first")).length
```

Comment: Yes, but not for the nested ones but only for the **<td>**.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
//For FFox
$(document).ready(function(){
var countTD=$("Your_Table_ID_or_Class tr:first > td").length;
});

// For webKit Browser
$(window).load(function(){
var countTD=$("Your_Table_ID_or_Class tr:first > td").length;
});
```

Note; If you creating dynamic table row column then use
`$(document).live("click",function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var itemsCount = $(".PrintTable > tr > td").length;
```

**Update:**

I just realized that at least Chrome inserts `<tbody>` if it isn't already present, so to get cross browser support:

```
var itemsCount = $(".PrintTable > tbody > tr > td, .PrintTable > tr > td").length;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/H2JWS/

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to count the number of `td`'s in a specific row, you can do this..

```
$(function(){
  count = $("table tr").children("td").index()+1; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalTable = $(remove_copy_drargelement).closest('table').clone();

var tds = $(originalTable).children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').length;
```