# css dynamic icon layout without refresh, similar to amazon's website

Tags: html, css, dynamic, layout

I'm fairly new to stylesheet so this maybe a very simple question.  I noticed that Amazon's website has 2 really cool features that I would like to replicate.

1. At the middle of the page, there is a grid that lay out icons horizontally for their recommendations and other stuff.  Depending on the width of the page, it shows either 4 or 5, or 6 up to 8 icons/items horizontally.  They do this without refreshing the page.  I tried to read the source, but it looks like a bunch of stylesheet trick that is making this happen.
2. The "Shop by Department" on the left is also very interesting. If your page is narrow, it disappears, but it shows up when you mouseover.  If the page is wide, then it shows up.

If anyone can point me to the right direction or some sample code, it would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

It's not just css.

Use a table to store however many elements you want in every row, and then set a general width to the whole table.

Use a javascript/jquery to calculate the width for each element according to that table size.

Question 2:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-31-fixed-fluid-fixed/
You might want to take a look at that. As far as I see on Amazon's site, the sidebar never dissappears.

Edit:

1.Say you have a page of 1000px width.
2.First 200 px from the left is set for the sidebar.
3.Use jQuery to check the current page width. 
4.if pageWidth<1000px, sidebar{display:none;}

But really, these codes are everywhere on the net.

Comment: Q1: So javascript/jquery determines re-draws the table depending on the width?  Q2: I may not have explained it well, try making the whole page narrower.  The Shop by Departments (on the left) disappears.

Comment: A answer to question one is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728907/finding-the-count-of-td-jquery Once u get the number of td's in each tr, u can do whatever u want.