# count of tr with style property empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html

```
<table id="tbl1">
  <tbody >
         <tr class="hide_grid_header"></tr>
         <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
         <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
          <tr ></tr>
         <tr style=""></tr>
         <tr ></tr>
         <tr style=""></tr>
         <tr ></tr>
       <tr style="display: none;"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

From this, I want count of tr which dont have style property OR with style=" "
property.

i'm using below code, but its giving me count as 8 instead of 5.

```
 var docs = jQuery("#tbl").find('tbody').find('tr:visible');
alert(docs.length);
```

Comment: something like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728907/finding-the-count-of-td-jquery?rq=1

Comment: Maybe because  you didn't use our answers?! anyway, you select the wrong table, you're missing  `1` in the id  selector: `jQuery("#tbl1 tr:visible").length;`

Answer (score 4):

```
$('tr').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).attr('style');
}).length;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var len = $('tr').filter(function(){
      return !$(this).attr('style');
}).length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pHt6/

Comment: Ohh the *"4 then 5 issue"*, a known bug... (kidding)

Comment: @gdoron It seems I was buggy, not the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.filter()`:

```
console.log($('table tr').filter('[style]').length);
```

`.filter()` filters out the collection of objects.

#### [CHECKOUT FIDDLE WITH FILTER USED](http://jsfiddle.net/DJR7L/)

`.not()`:

```
console.log($('table tr').not('[style]').length);
```

`This will output all the tr length which doesn't have a style attributes.`

#### [CHECKOUT FIDDLE WITH NOT USED](http://jsfiddle.net/DJR7L/1/)

Comment: good answer..thats working good

Comment: @sasi, except it's wrong...  it selects 5 instead of 6.

Comment: @gdoron why it should select 6. There are just 5 trs with style property.

Comment: _"I want count of tr which dont have style property **OR with style=" "** property."_ **there're 4 tr without style at all and 2 more with empty style=6**

Answer (score 0):

**Selecting each collection separately**:

```
var $tr_blank_style = $('tr[style=""]'); // with style=""
var $tr_no_style    = $('tr:not([style])'); // no style attribute at all
var $tr_count       = $tr_blank_style.length + $tr_no_style.length;
```

**Using `filter` to select both together**:

```
var $tr_count = $('tr').filter(function() {
        return $(this).is('[style=""],:not([style])'); 
    }).length;
```