# Jquery:- Count number of td in each tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I count td in each row, It should say row 1 have two td and row 3 have one td.
I need to count td per row(tr)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.Create-New-Order').click(function() {
    var total = $('#mytbl td').length;
    alert('tr count = ' + total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1px solid red">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="mytbl">
    <tr>
      <td>sfdsd</td>
      <td>tsdaf@ymail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sfdsd</td>
      <td>tsdaf@ymail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sfdsd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" class="Create-New-Order">Create-New-Order</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please share your code. What do you want to do with the counts? Have you tried Google for `tr` and `td` select?

Comment: um, select them and read length?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: count number of td in a table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728907/finding-the-count-of-td-jquery/4728978)

Comment: @devlincarnate its just counting rows not, cells in each row

Comment: @developer - I updated it

Comment: @devlincarnate if you run my code snippet, its doing same, it count all the td's in a table. But again my issue is, I need to count td in each row.

Comment: To get the cell counts use a jQuery each on the `tr` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over each row and then get the number of cells with `$(this).find('td').length`:

```js
$('.Create-New-Order').click(function() {
  var total = $('#mytbl tr').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('td').length)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1px solid red">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="mytbl">
    <tr>
      <td>sfdsd</td>
      <td>tsdaf@ymail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sfdsd</td>
      <td>tsdaf@ymail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sfdsd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<a href="#" class="Create-New-Order">Create-New-Order</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy first get all rows the loop throw each and count the td.

See below

```js
    $(function() {
      $('.Create-New-Order').click(function() {
        var trs=document.querySelectorAll("#mytbl tr")
        trs.forEach(function(tr){
          console.log(tr.querySelectorAll("td").length)
        })

        
      });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <table border="1px solid red">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody id="mytbl">
        <tr>
          <td>sfdsd</td>
          <td>tsdaf@ymail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sfdsd</td>
          <td>tsdaf@ymail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sfdsd</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="Create-New-Order">Create-New-Order</a>
```

Comment: Any idea how can we do same in pure js?

Comment: Yes will change it for you

Comment: See upp did it with pure js